# Cannot find Wood Harness reference

Tags: the-dark-eye, the-dark-eye-5

In the *The Dark Eye Aventuria Compendium*, page 215 has a break down of the stats and equipment for the *Dajin-Buskur* template.

Its equipment section makes a mention of a **Wood Harness** as the first item. Now the only wooden item in the Armor section of *Aventuria Compendium* is **Wooden Armor** on page 230.

The *Aventuria Armory* book has no reference to either **Wooden Armor** or **Wood Harness**.

So, is there a book that talks about difference in materials being used to create the armors or is this just not reference yet?

Comment: Can you quote the mention of a "wood harness"?

Comment: Yes, when I get home I will get the quote.

Comment: Hey there! We're working on potentially relabeling some questions related to The Dark Eye. In order to help us out, can you tell us what edition of DSA this question is about? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Wood Harness** is a **Wooden Armor**.¹

The sample character **Dajin-Buskur** in the *Aventuria Compendium* uses a **Wooden Armor** as his armor. 
Additionally previous editions of of *The Dark Eye* did not include other types of **Wooden Armor**.

¹: I'm unsure if this is an error. The german translation also uses two different names for both (*Hartholzharnisch* & *Holzrüstung*). It could be planned, that specific rules for a wood harness will be added in a later book, and until then this should be used. Other source books about regions add region specific weapons and armor.

Comment: The "Maraskanischer Hartholzharnisch" is an item that backdates to the old Maraskan box. It was featured (among others) in "Kaiser Retos Waffenkammer" for DSA3 as much as it was in "Aventurisches Arsenal" for DSA4 and the "Wege des Schwertes" for DSA4.1 ; It traditionally has (almost) the same states as any other wooden armor.

Answer (score 4):

Hartholzharnisch is in the Aventurian Armory 2 which is currently only available in German.